# How html attribute onblur and javascript trigger blur event work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

How HTML attribute `onblur` and jQuery `.trigger("blur")` event work?

will both events execute like javascript `this.trigger("blur")` work first and then HTML attribute `onblur` work or only one event will be fired?

I am using `onblur` attribute on an input element and in some scenarios I have triggered that event using javascript but my function is executing multiple times. I think the blur event fired two times, so how I can fired it only once?

Here is HTML element.

```html
<input class="form-control"
       type="text"
       id="ListDisplay"
       onblur="changeVal()"
       autocomplete="off"
       value="${name}"
       display="${name}"
/>
```

Here is the jquery event on which blur triggered. in this showSuggestionListItem is a dynamic dropdown.

```js
$(".showSuggestionListItem").off('mousedown').on('mousedown',
  function () {
    $('#ListDisplay').trigger("blur");                          
  }
);
```

Here is changeVal function of onblur.

```
function changeVal(){
    alert('called');
}
```

Comment: what is `elem`? what is `. showSuggestionListItem`

Comment: Why don't you simply call that function instead of calling/triggering irrelevant obfuscating events?  Think as a programmer, if you need to call `changeVal` you immediately know what you're doing. If instead you call `.blur()` or `trigger("blur")` you have to go throughout the entire codebase to lookup and understand what it's supposed to do and what will happen in return. `.on('mousedown', changeVal)` is way cleaner than anything else.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your current example is confusing and does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using `onBlur` attribute simply assigns the callback to the Blur event. `.trigger("blur")` triggers a `blur` event.

As you have a trigger in another event, the act of clicking outside of the text field triggers a blur event that may bubble up before the `mousedown` event; hence why you get two `blur` events triggered.

I would advise the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function changeVal() {
    console.log('Blur called');
  }
  $("#ListDisplay").blur(changeVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ListDisplay" autocomplete="off" value="${name}" display="${name}" />
```